# Print the Multiplication of Values in Separate Dictionaries Together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
AvailConcertSeats = {"The Weeknd": 80000, "Maroon 5": 80000, "Justin Bieber": 80000, "Post Malone": 34000}

AvgConcertPrice = {"The Weeknd": 200, "Maroon 5": 109, "Justin Bieber": 250, "Post Malone": 179}
```

I'd like to print out the multiplication of `AvailConcertSeats` values x `AvgConcertPrice` values.

Code I've tried:

```
AvailConcertSeats.values() * AvgConcertPrice.values()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```py
AvailConcertSeats = {"The Weeknd": 80000, "Maroon 5": 80000, "Justin Bieber": 80000, "Post Malone": 34000}
AvgConcertPrice = {"The Weeknd": 200, "Maroon 5": 109, "Justin Bieber": 250, "Post Malone": 179}

output = {k: seats * AvgConcertPrice[k] for k, seats in AvailConcertSeats.items()}
print(output)
# {'The Weeknd': 16000000, 'Maroon 5': 8720000, 'Justin Bieber': 20000000, 'Post Malone': 6086000}
```

If you want to be "safe" (when the keys of the two dicts are possibly not identical), the following will only calculate on the intersection of them:

```py
output = {k: AvailConcertSeats[k] * AvgConcertPrice[k] for k in AvailConcertSeats.keys() & AvgConcertPrice.keys()}
```